# Unable to execute SMP (SAP Mobile Platform) in android

Tags: android, smp

I have integrate OData service and successfully open OData store but while reading an Entity set i am getting following ODataNetworkException: Unknown network response error occured. Anyone have any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Share your Logcat detail

Comment: @Herry: my issue was resolved but now i am getting issue in Lollipop OS which already asked by keyur in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852799/smp-integration-with-android  please answer if you have any solution on that post.