# SMP integration with Android

Tags: android, sap-smp

I am facing one issue with **SMP** integration with Android. My question is: When i try to run my application in **android OS 5.0 & +** device i am getting error mentioned below.

```
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sybase.mo.MessagingClientException" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 

"/data/app/sample.UI.Droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/Sample.UI.Droid-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]".**
```

But its working fine with pre-Lollipop devices.

Full logs are in below link:
http://pastebin.com/8kfhXDCT

Comment: did upgrading to the most recent sdk service pack solve your problem? i'm on SP12 and i still get the same mentioned exception on devices running android 5 or 6

Comment: @daco:  check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my error by removing **DataVaultLib-2.3.3.13.jar** and adding **SUPProxyClient-2.3.3.jar**  and **ClientLib.jar**.

Now My app is working properly in **Lollipop** and **Marshmallow** OS

I go through this [link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/7025a332-7535-3010-37a6-da6503584776?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&57909044096911) and for [jar](https://github.com/manoj-mathivanan/androidapps/tree/master/sample_app/libs)

Answer (score 2):

Removing **maflogonimo-1.212.2.jar** (or other version from respective service pack) will fix the problem in SMP 3.0 environments.

I just learned, that this specific library is only used for backwards compatibility with the SUP, but breaks the app when used with a SMP 3.0 only.

Comment: See SAP-Note for further information: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002211719

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you are using the updated SDK version to support Lollipop. Andriod 5 support was added in SMP SDK SP07.

You could refer to this [SAP Note](https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/sno/ui_entry/entry.htm?param=69765F6D6F64653D3030312669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D3139333338353726) to check the list of devices supported by SMP 3.